# How to terminate (kill) another application in a FireMonkey application?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, firemonkey-fm3

Does someone know a solution to kill another application in FMX ? 
Having the name of the application to terminate, I want to be able to kill a Windows or MAC OSX application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no option for that in FireMonkey itself.  You have to use platform-specific APIs, like `TerminateProcess()` on Windows.